# How to use another js from some js file?

Tags: javascript, jasmine, jasmine-node

Recently I am trying to use jasmine-node to run unit test from console.

The problem is that my unit test test.js file is in another directory of the source source.js file.

How do I make sure my unit test test.js file can refer to the method of the source.js file?

Folder struture

```
spec\test.js
js\source.js
```

Comment: have a look to require.js http://requirejs.org/docs/start.html#examples. It might help

Answer (score 1):

You'd have to use some module dependency tool, like [browserify](http://browserify.org/), [requireJS](http://requirejs.org/) or [webpack](http://webpack.github.io/).

You'd need to export your code's variables:

```
//js/source.js
var SourceComponent = 'Hello'; // what you want to export
module.exports = SourceComponent; // export that variable
```

You can now include your source by calling
`require('js/source');`

Setting this up can take a while, as you often need to make sure all dependencies are tied together, which can take a long time with large projects.

We used the **webpack**, which has helped, as you can “emulate” it being run in a script tag.

In webpack we imported source files like follows:
`require(script!js/source.js');` which allowed us to quickly get something working.